# Footer with resizing issue css

Tags: html, css, resize, footer

I am beginner in website programming and I having an issue that I just cant resolve. The issue I am having is that when I re-size Google chrome or any browser, the items in the footer do not online and the copyright disappears at certain sizes when resizing. I do not see what I am doing wrong and this is my first time making a website. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code. Please help.

Following is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Yes ICAN: International Child Advocacy Network</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css"/>
    <meta name"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scaled=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <img id="header" src="img/header.jpg"/>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="chat.html">Get Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://community.yesican.org">Community</a></li>
                <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About YIC</a></li>
                <li><a href="supportyic.html">Get Involved</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <img id="banner" src="img/banner.jpg"/>
    <!--The main content of the website will go inside of the #wrapper id. It is divided into two sections: #primary & #secondary.-->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Two sections have been created for desktop view to have two columns. Mobile website will just be stacked-->
        <section id="primary">
            <h2>Who We Are</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in elementum velit, venenatis rhoncus lacus. Ut consequat luctus enim, in auctor libero posuere ut. Curabitur vitae aliquet nisi. Etiam condimentum tincidunt venenatis. Fusce vel congue purus. Pellentesque ut eleifend ex. Nunc purus neque, aliquam vitae aliquam quis, accumsan id lacus. Nunc ac scelerisque magna. Etiam purus lorem, rutrum et ornare a, tincidunt non ipsum. Nullam blandit dui venenatis, malesuada felis a, porttitor purus.</p>
            <!--Left column content goes here-->
        </section>

        <section id="secondary">
        <h2>Memorial List</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in elementum velit, venenatis rhoncus lacus. Ut consequat luctus enim, in auctor libero posuere ut.</p>
            <!--Right column content goes here-->
        </section>
    </div>

    <!--Footer still needs to be completed-->
    <footer>
        <div id="footerslogan"> 
            <p>BREAK THE <b>SILENCE</b> <br>AND <b>CYCLE</b> OF ABUSE</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul><h3>ABOUT</h3>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">FAQ's</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Site Map</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul><h3>SUPPORT OUR CAUSE</h3>
                <li><a href="">Donate</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Volunteer</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Fundraising Events</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul><h3>FOLLOW US</h3>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Facebook handle here"><img src="img/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
                    <a href="#Instagram handle here"><img src="img/instagram-icon.png" alt="Instagram Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
                    <a href="#Twitter handle here"><img src="img/twitter-icon.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"/></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
                    <!--If we decide to do a copyright on the page Tiff. It is commented it out below.-->
                <p id="copyright">Copyright&copy; 2013 International Child Advocacy Network</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>



Here is the css code:



        /***********************
    GENERAL
    ***********************/
    a {
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    img {

        max-width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        font-family: 'Fabrica', Arial;
        background-color:#e6e9ed;
        color: #434a54;
    }

    #wrapper{
        max-width:960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color:#f5f7fa;
        overflow: auto; /*This fixed the wrapper background color problem that happened bc floating content*/
    }

    #banner {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        padding: 0;
        display:block;
        clear:both;
    }

    /***********************
    HEADER
    ***********************/
    #header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    font-family: 'Fabrica', Arial;
    }  

    /***********************
    NAVIGATION
    ***********************/
    nav{
        background:#4a89dc;
        text-align:center;
        color:blue;
        max-width:960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:1.2em;
    }
    nav ul{
        list-style:none;
        margin:0 10px; /*Can be change later on in the design if it doesn't work*/
    }
    nav li{
        /*Inline, mostly text. Appears in the same line, inline as the rest of the text. Block 
          pushes other items out of the page. Inline block maintains width and 
          height but is in line with other images*/
        display:inline-block;
        list-style:none;
    }
    nav a{
        font-weight: 800;
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }

    nav a:visited, a:link {
        color:#f5f7fa;
    }

    nav a:link {
        color:#f5f7fa;
    }

    nav a:hover {
        color:#0B108C;
    }
    /**********************
    FOOTER
    **********************/
    footer {
        max-width:950px;
        background-color:#434a54;
        font-size:0.75em;
        text-align:center;
        clear:both; /* The clear property allows the footer to be clear of any floated elements */
        color:#e6e9ed;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 4px;
        font-family: 'Fabrica', Arial;
    }
    footer h3{
        padding-left: .9em;
    }
    footer ul {
        display:inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align:left;
    }
    footer ul li{
        list-style:none;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding-left: 1em;
    }
    footer ul li a{
        color:#e6e9ed;
    }

    footer a:hover {
        color:#FFFFFF; /*Change hover color to make it more prominent*/
    }

    #footerslogan{
        padding-top: .6em;
        float:left;     
        padding-left: 2em;
        font-size: 1.35em;
    }
    #copyright{
        font-size: .75em;
        text-align:left;
        margin-top: 5px; 
        float:left;
        clear:both;
        display:inline-block;
    }   
    .social-icon {
    /*Everything here is a placeholder for the images*/
        display:inline-block;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
    }
    img.social-icon {
        border-square: 85%;
        margin-bottom: .8em;
        margin-right: .9em;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, i noticed some typing errors;  hope they were just typo.  Here is the updated/corrected part.  You had no "=" before viewport and had added "d" to initial-scale!

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I would suggest you make use of getbootstrap.com or jquerymobile.com to get rid of many problems similar to the one you are facing.

Comment: I will investigate into these sites and are these sites going to take away the programming experience? I am still learning and would like to keep on learning

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to put the Copyright on the left bottom corner, you can use `position: absolute` for the #copyright and set the parent div as `position: relative`. I posted the code below.

```
footer>div {
    position: relative;
}

#copyright {
    font-size: .75em;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you're looking for something else, please explain more about what you want to do.

I would also recommend using something like http://jsfiddle.net/ and attach all files you used (such as normalize.css and responsive.css) to be easier to view your problem.

Comment: I would like my site to be mobile friendly as well and so I wouldn't consider doing that. I would appreciate any books or reference to look more into this. Thank you for your help though, I appreciate